# maven: read sonar.login from properties file

Tags: maven, properties, sonarqube, properties-file

I'm trying to setup **sonar.login** property so that it is outside of pom.xml. I tried using *properties-maven-plugin* from *codehaus* but it fails to see the property (and I don't see that much information about how to debug it to show me like the property file being read and the values that it retrieved).

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${basedir}/sonar.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The properties file inside has something like:

```
sonar.login=some-value
```

The only thing that works is setting the property on mvn call:

```
mvn -Dsonar.login=some-value sonar:sonar
```

How can I get these properties file to be read so that `mvn sonar:sonar` works as intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${basedir}/sonar.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

plugin should be kept inside the build

Comment: yeah... that's where it is... it doesn work. Let me specify it on the answer, just in case.

Comment: looks like its not able to execute the properties plugin.  Associate properties-maven-plugin to 'verify' phase instead of 'initialize'. Then run as mvn verify sonar:sonar

Comment: Setting it to verify didn't change the outcome... still not working.